# Loop Within Loop in iMacro

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have the following code in a js file:

```
i = 0
do
{
i=i+1;

//Set Date +4
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 4;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth();
var y = someDate.getFullYear();

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

ret=iimSet("someFormattedDate",someFormattedDate = monthNames[mm] + ' '+ dd + ','+ y);

// Opens Order Page Loop
ret=iimSet("myloop", i);
ret=iimPlay("sfiles/#Loop_Extract_1.iim");

// Extract and set order statuss
var status=iimGetLastExtract();

// Continue if order statuss processing
if( status.toLowerCase().indexOf('processing') >= 0){
ret=iimSet("someFormattedDate",someFormattedDate = monthNames[mm] + ' '+ dd + ','+ y);
ret=iimPlay ("sfiles/#Loop_1.iim");
}

}

while (ret  > 0);
```

This plays Loop_Extract_1.iim on loop, the contents of which are a follows:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
'Set Data source excel sheet
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Script_Excel\orders.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{myloop}}
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com/post.php?post={{!COL1}}&action=edit
```

Then, it play Loop1.iim, the contents of which are as follows:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX

TAB T=1

'Click on Load in Order Viewer Button
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:layers
```

I need to define another loop inside Loop_1.iim, such that the POS is defined by the number written in column 2 of the datasource sheet. For example - if coloumn 2 has 3, Loop_1.iim should play with POS=1, then it should play with POS=2 and so on till it reaches 3. How to do this?

Comment: Yep, a "Loop within a Loop" is called a "Nested Loop", many Threads about that on SOF and on the iMacros Forum... [Idea]

Comment: Buggy Site: "Comments 5min..."

Yep, a "Loop within a Loop" is called a "Nested Loop", manyThreads about that here on SOF I would think and certainly on the iMacros Forum... [Idea]
If you don't come out by yourself, you can open a Thread on the iMacros Forum (I don't like answering Threads on this Forum), if you can manage to spell "iMacros" correctly on this Forum, + mention your FCI, and on the iMacros Forum as well of course...
(And we can always post the Final Solution on this Forum of course...)